# SQL list of things LIKE

Tags: sql, list, sql-like

Instead of doing a query in SQL such as:

```
SELECT QUARTERSECTION WHERE
LABEL LIKE 'NE%' or LABEL LIKE 'SW%'
```

Is there anyway, I can a query to group values together
`LABEL LIKE IN ('NE%', 'SW%')`?

Comment: What RDBMS do you use? Some support regular expression matching, which can do what you want. But if it's just a few patterns to match, stick with `LIKE` and `OR`.

Comment: And if they're all the same length, you could also use a truncated string with `IN`() as in `LEFT(LABEL, 2) IN ('NE', 'SW')`

Answer (score 1):

You can create the temp table and put all like values there, then use Join

```
CREATE TABLE tempKeywordSearch (
  keyword VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO tempKeywordSearch  VALUES ('NE%'), ('SW%');

SELECT q.* 
FROM QUARTERSECTION q 
JOIN tempKeywordSearch t ON (q.col LIKE t.keyword);
```

Comment: im doing this in GIS software. doesn't support multiple line text.

Comment: but  the LEFT(label,2) helped a lot!

Comment: @user2375756:- before asking the question, you have to mention all about your environment, if specific